# How to sync to specific folder using command line in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

Suppose I have mapped my depot to client workspace as `c:/perforce/project` but now

I want to sync all the files present in `c:/perforce/project/fold1/fold2` folder.

How can we do it, as the command p4 sync takes only file names and not folder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Say the depot path is //depot/project/...

From the command line, do `p4 sync //depot/project/fold1/fold2/...`

(the "..." tells Perforce you want that folder and everything under it).

From P4V, right-click on the folder and choose "Get Latest Revision". It will only pull in the folder and everything underneath it.

Comment: You can also do this using local or relative paths, e.g. cd to c:\perforce\project and then "p4 sync fold1/fold2/..."

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks for pointing "..." tells Perforce you want that folder and everything under it. I was missing it. Can you also tell the command for getting Workspace directory and Workspace name.

Comment: Something like "p4 sync C:/mydir/myfolder/..." will work IF that path is under your default p4 workspace setting.  (Since I typically have several workspaces going, I use .p4config just to make sure I'm in the right place and syncing what I want to sync).

Comment: this seems to be accepting file paths only not folder paths, I tried folder path and I get message `- no such files(s).`

Comment: Yes, P4 tracks things by file, so if you don't have any files in a folder you could get that message.